# qpython in android giving me 'permission denied' when trying subprocess.Popen

Tags: android, python, subprocess, qpython

I'm trying to build a chess GUI for android using stockfish engine.

But whenever I try to use subprocess I get the permission denied error

I don't know how to give any permission to qpython since I'm a beginner in programming.

I know that I'm missing something here , what should I do ?

By the way my android is rooted , if that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

What command are you trying to run?

'ls' is available without taking root.

```
#qpy:http://qpython.com/s/sample.py
try:
    import androidhelper
    import subprocess

    droid = androidhelper.Android()
    s = subprocess.check_output("ls")
    droid.dialogCreateAlert("title", s)
    droid.dialogSetPositiveButtonText("Yes")
    droid.dialogSetNegativeButtonText("No")
    droid.dialogShow() 
except:
    print("Hello, Please update to newest QPython version from (http://play.qpython.com/qrcode-python.html) to use this feature")
```